# Does Ubuntu 18.04 have an icon called "System"?

Tags: icons

I ask this question because some of my searches for information tell me to click on "System" and execute certain actions. I can't see any icon called "System" in the list of Activities which my Ubuntu screen is displaying. Do I need to look elsewhere or am I missing something?
Thanks.
Steve.

Hello User535733 and thanks for replying. I only installed Ubuntu 2 days ago having downloaded the ISO file and formatted a USB stick. You may be right about me looking at old instructions but if so, what should I be looking for on my Ubuntu desktop? Yugan Tej (thanks for replying) points me to the bar along the top of my screen and I can open a file called "Settings" but I don't think that's the one.
I'm either looking in the wrong place or I need to install something, hence my question.
Thanks.
Thanks for responding, DsStorm. I'm trying to find out stuff about Ubuntu and I often come across people referring to the "Systems" folder. As I can't see one on my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04), that's why I have asked the question.
Rather than fire off loads of questions to you experienced users, and take up your valuable time, I think it's more sensible for me to look for tutorials etc and master the basics first. 
Thanks everyone.
Regards
Steve.

Comment: An example would be most helpful. The GUI has changed several times, you might be looking at old instructions.

Comment: @stevepets you may be searching for top right on the top bar

Comment: what actions do you want to do?

Comment: I think you are looking for "System Settings" which leads to many system subsystems you can configure.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are looking for **settings** or **system settings** as detailed in this question:

- [Difference between settings and system settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067562/difference-between-settings-and-system-settings)

I have two programs called `settings`. Is there a reason to have two of them?

[image]

`settings`:

[image]

`system settings`:

[image]

This is a typical Linux system design issue and would never happen on Mac or Win.